# emacs info mode: back to previous page

Tags: emacs

In Emacs info mode, it is possible to press `<ent>` on a hyperlink to follow it. However, it is possible to return to the previous page after opening the link? Also, it is possible to open the link in a new buffer (other than the default `*info*`)?

Note that I use the command line, so any GUI feature won't work.

Comment: I found it in the help of `Info-mode`. `l`: Move back in history to the last node you were at.

Comment: Make sure you post and accept your answer. Be sure to spend some time familiarising yourself with the info reader bindings and features in general -- it's usefulness simply can't be overstated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `M-n` to open the link under point in a new buffer.